# Getting number of files in StorageFolder

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I was working with a Windows Phone 8.1(RT) application, I wanted to know how to get **the number of files inside a StorageFolder**.

I know we can use `StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync()` and then check the count of this list returned.
But since this method takes too long and returns all items is there more efficient method of getting this done?

Comment: Are you only trying to get files from your own isolated storage directory, or are you trying to get them from somewhere else (eg Pictures library or Music library)?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT: From the LocalStorage of the App(Isolated) but would like to know both if possible.

Comment: There is not direct way to get the count. But as these files are saved by the app you can keep track of added/removed files in localsettings and use for quick access you can get number of files from localSettings. 
P.S local storage even does not provides file exists :( one has to access the file in try catch to check if file exists or not

Comment: @MuhammadSaifullah : Currently using the localsettings approach somehow I'm not really satisfied with this approach.Thanks for the suggestion. Hopefully Microsoft ups its game with win10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get 3 orders of magnitude faster performance if you use Win32 APIs to get the file count, but it only works for your local storage directory (it won't work for brokered locations such as Pictures or Music). For example, given the following C++/CX component:

**Header**

```
public ref struct FilePerfTest sealed
{
  Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<uint32>^ GetFileCountWin32Async();
  uint32 GetFileCountWin32();
};
```

**Implementation**

```
uint32 FilePerfTest::GetFileCountWin32()
{
  std::wstring localFolderPath(ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->Path->Data());
  localFolderPath += L"\\Test\\*";
  uint32 found = 0;
  WIN32_FIND_DATA findData{0};
  HANDLE hFile = FindFirstFileEx(localFolderPath.c_str(), FindExInfoBasic, &findData, FindExSearchNameMatch, nullptr, FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH);

  if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    throw ref new Platform::Exception(GetLastError(), L"Can't FindFirstFile");
  do
  {
    if ((findData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0)
      ++found;
  } while (FindNextFile(hFile, &findData) != 0);

  auto hr = GetLastError();
  FindClose(hFile);
  if (hr != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
    throw ref new Platform::Exception(hr, L"Error finding files");

  return found;
}

Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<uint32>^ FilePerfTest::GetFileCountWin32Async()
{
  return concurrency::create_async([this]
  {
    return GetFileCountWin32();
  });
}
```

If I test this on my Lumia 920 in **Release** mode to get 1,000 files, the Win32 version takes less than 5 *milliseconds* (faster if you use the non-async version, and at that speed there's really no need to be async) whereas using `StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync().Count` takes more than 6 *seconds*.

**Edit 7/1/15**

Note that if you are targeting Windows Desktop apps, you can use the `StorageFolder.CreateFileQuery` method to create a bulk query, and that should be faster. But unfortunately it isn't supported on Phone 8.1

Comment: This is nice but I was wondering if there were any other method for querying somewhere else in the file system? It didn't even work for a c:\myfolder and I need to query a folder with 35k files :(

Comment: Unfortunately there is no supported way. If this is just for your own enjoyment (not something to put in the Store) you can try ACL-ing the folder to give read access to `ALL APPLICATION PACAKGES`... but use at your own risk, it's probably not supported, etc.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Unfortunately is something I want to eventually publish in the store. What I ended doing was to incrementally read files in a batchs but that's not ideal. Is this going to be fixed in Windows 10?

Comment: The post is tagged for Phone but your example folder sounds like PC. Either way, as I noted in the edit, there is a better mechanism using File Queries but there's no good way to get the folder in the first place; you have to get the user to pick it with a `FolderPicker`. This should also work on Phone in Windows 10

Comment: Thanks Peter. My app is indeed targetted to PCs. I did try doing a query but GetItemCountAsync is giving me the amount of subfolders instead of files. Thanks for the edit though!

Comment: Make sure you use the right query -- I think the no-arg version gives folders, but there is a version that takes a CommonQuery and I believe Default works.

Comment: I tried that one with default but it didn't work for me... Now that I'm thinking I should post this as a question :)