# How to get size in bytes of a StorageFolder on Windows Phone 8.1 (Universal App)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a better way on **Windows Phone 8.1 XAML/Universal App** how to get **total size of all files including nested files in a specific StorageFolder** than recursively traversing all folders and counting manually size of all files?

Solution that works on Windows 8.1 (tablets/PC) is using CommonFileQuery that returns all nested files within specific folder.

```
StorageFileQueryResult filesQuery = downloads.CreateFileQuery(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await filesQuery.GetFilesAsync();
```

then you can Sum the size of all files easily. Unfortunately there is no working Query method on Windows Phone 8.1 that works in any folder and return deep list of files of a folder.

**Update**, just tested on Lumia 520 and getting size of a folder with 4 subfolders, each with single file using this method takes 1150 ms, that's just too much!

Comment: Look here for improving speed if it is your own data folder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908345/getting-number-of-files-in-storagefolder/29913403#29913403